# How can I use a Hibernate validator without an annotation on a field?

Tags: hibernate

Is it possible to use the Hibernate validator API storing the validated object in a field with an annotation? For example, I would like to validate `Email` address by calling a Java method instead of putting an `@Email` annotation on a Java bean property.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Try Something like,

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

Car car = new Car(null);

Set<ConstraintViolation<Car>> constraintViolations =
    validator.validateProperty(car, "manufacturer");
```

Take a look at [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#d0e590).

Answer (score 4):

zinan.yumaks solution where they are creating a dummy `Car` object that you don't need is not the right way to do this. There is a better solution, the [`validateValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html#validateValue%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class...%29) method:

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();

String emailAddress = "...";

Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = 
    validator.validateValue(User.class, "email", emailAddress);
```

From the documentation:

> Validates all constraints placed on the property named `propertyName` of the class `beanType` would the property value be `value`.

Comment: Re: "creating a dummy Car object that you don't need" - the example that you show though is using an instance of Car.  The OP is (and I am!) trying to achieve this without an object at all.. eg is string "xyz@yahoo.com" a valid email address?

Comment: @RoyTruelove: Hm, I seem to have been confused in some way when I wrote this, and now I can't remember the details. Thanks for pointing it out. It looks like `validateValue` is the right way to do this, but that the last argument should be the value being validated, ex `manufacturer` or `emailAddress`. I'll update the answer to that effect (although I haven't tested it).