# How to allow javax.validation to be ignored in some cases

Tags: java, hibernate, validation

Given the following class

```
public class Website {

    @NotNull
    String owner:

    @ValidUrl
    String url;

}
```

When we validate that (e.g. using @Valid) and if Website.url does not respect my custom @ValidUrl constraint we'll get an constraint violation (e.g. "url is unreachable").

I was wondering if it is possible to ignore that validation if the user wants to.

Steps:

1. Validate form for the 1st time
2. Throw constraint violation and show it to the user
3. User chooses "I know, add it anyway" and re-submit
4. Validate form for the 2nd time, validating everything except @ValidUrl

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this by a combination of using [validation groups](http://in.relation.to/Bloggers/BeanValidationSneakPeekPartIIIGroupsAndPartialValidation) and [programmatic validatio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533130/using-hibernate-validator-without-calling-annotation)n.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way you can remove a violation from a set of violation.

```
public static <T> Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> removeViolation(final Set<ConstraintViolation<T>> constraintViolations, final String propertyName, final Class annotationClass) {
    return constraintViolations.stream().filter(p ->
            !(((NodeImpl) (((PathImpl) (p.getPropertyPath())).getLeafNode())).getName().equals(propertyName))
                    || !((ConstraintDescriptorImpl) p.getConstraintDescriptor()).getAnnotationType().getSimpleName().equals(annotationClass.getSimpleName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
```